# How can i test from the emulator a cloud function?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, cloud

i have a cloud function like this

```
exports.isWhite = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  return cors(request, response, async () => {
    try {
      const { query } = request
      let { address } = query
      address = address.toLowerCase()
```

but i dont know how can i test it from the emulator?

i put this url http://localhost:5001/roor-dev-ff624/us-central1/isWhitelisted on my browser, how can i pass the address? because i am getting this error:

```
"[ !!! ] Error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined\n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) parameters. To pass the address that way, try changing the URL to:

```
http://localhost:5001/roor-dev-ff624/us-central1/isWhitelisted?address=some_address
```

---

You can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to avoid that error:

```
const address = request.query.address?.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Glad to hear that @brunodia. You might also want to add some check there so just in case the query param is missing it won't throw that error.

Comment: please help me with that error more please

Comment: @brunodia I've updated the answer. Can you check that out?

Comment: can you help me pleas with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70628328/how-can-i-deploy-my-cloud-function-nodejs